# Windows Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server license issues

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I want to run Office 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 via terminal services. I have the key for Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and I have the CALs for Windows Terminal Server 2008 and key for Office 2010 Pro Plus.

Do I just need to add the license server on another box, and does this additional box need a terminal server license too?

Comment: TS 2008 keys aren't good on 2008R2. You can put the TS License service on the same server, or another. TS Licensing is much more complicated than "normal" Windows licensing and I highly recommend you get someone involved who really knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on terminal services this means that you will have more then one instance of it running.  I think you need to [get a different key for Office](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx), the volume activation key.  After you setup the KMS server you will need the [Microsoft Office 2010 KMS Host License Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=97b7b710-6831-4ce5-9ff5-fdc21fe8d965&displaylang=en).  Here is a [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624357.aspx#section2) on setting up the KMS host and Office volume activation.